# Understanding: "uploading phpliteadmin to a web server" in Windows 10

Tags: php

PhpLiteAdmin is said to be a very light sql manager that needs no installation. However, the instructions says:

`phpliteadmin.php is dropped into a directory on a server and then visited in a browser.`

A blog suggests:

`Drop the script to the document root of your server, and point your browser to http://127.0.0.1/phpliteadmin.php`

And I have no idea how to do that.

I have: 1. installed XAMPI and started both Apache and MySQL. 2. I have tried to access `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0`.

Then, the question is: how do I upload phpliteadmin.php to a web server and then access it. Thanks.

Comment: So you can access 127.0.0.1 successfully in browser?

Comment: Yes. But I get the XAMPI dashboard. And I was unable to import the phpliteadmin I have in file (a lot of erros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed XAMPP locally on your machine you don't need to upload anything. If you start Apache and MySQL successfully you just need to move your `phpliteadmin.php` file to folder where apache can read it. By default for XAMPP this folder is in `<path_to_your_xampp_installation>/htdocs`, for example `C:\xampp\htdocs`.

Now if your apache is configured correctly you should be able to access this file by browser visiting `http://127.0.0.1/phpliteadmin.php`

Comment: That was it. I knew it was simple and I was missing it. Thanks.